# How to control position of axis label in persp3D in plot3D R package

Tags: r, plot

I have managed to create a 3D perspective surface plot using `persp3D` in `plot3D`. However when I rotate the plot, the default action is to make the "x2" axis labels "jump" to a point where they can't obscure the data. The effect of this is that an unconventional axis label is created which looks confusing. I would like to be able to keep the conventional axis labeling scheme that one would expect.

Here is the plot, which I have annotated showing the desired position of the x2 axis label, tick marks and tick mark labels.

[image: 3D plot]

Here is my code, which directly writes the jpg file, allowing me to conform accurately to the journal requirements:

```
jpeg(file="plot500-140-25a.jpg",width=3543,height=3543)

plot3D::persp3D(x,y,z=df3,theta=140, phi=25,xlab="x2",ylab="x1",zlab="Intensity",
cex.lab=10,cex.axis=5,ticktype="detailed")

dev.off()
```

What can I do to move the axis label, tick marks and tick mark labels to the desired position?

Comment: `persp3D` isn't an `rgl` function.  If you were using `rgl`, you could use `mtext3d` to draw text anywhere, but it would not appear on an angle as you want.  To do that, you'll likely need to draw it to a 2D graphic, then use `show2d` to place it in the scene.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I am confused though: in this rgl doc:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/rgl.pdf
 there is documentation of persp3D and plot3D. What am I missing? Are there multiple functions called persp3D and plot3D? Thanks

Comment: Those are `persp3d` and `plot3d`.  R is case sensitive, so those are different from the names with a capital D.

Comment: Thanks for that - understood.  Looks like I should try a different graphics package if I want to gain more control over where axis labels and tick marks go. Maybe matplotlib? Gnuplot? This website:
https://www.researchgate.net/post/Which_software_application_is_best_for_plotting_scientific_graphs
seems to have some promising leads, in case someone reading this in future has similar issues.

Comment: In case helpful for anyone else who finds themselves needing more customizable plotting routines, it seems that matplotlib can provide this. A good way to get this is to install Anaconda, which includes the Spyder scientific python interface as well as matplotlib, numpy, pandas and other useful routines. A website that is a very good tutorial can be found here: http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~fangohr/training/python/notebooks/Matplotlib.html